# DOM elements can not overlapping on canvas background

Tags: css, canvas

i am wondering to draw a full-window size canvas to my app's background, where all my other html tags like  and

could overlapping on it. 
As to be full window sized canvas, i have to set its height and width as `canvas.height = window.innerHeight` and `canvas.width = window.innerWidth` I am curious about to using CSS z-index properties to styling it.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body{
            margin:0;
        }

        canvas{
         position: absolute;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%; 
         z-index:1;
        }

        .container{
          position:absolute;
          z-index:2;
         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
 <div class="container">
    <h1>This is the heading</h1>
    <p>This is the place where we should put the content</p>
 </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
</script>
</html>
```

it seems not working properly, i am wondering am i right with the `z-index`at`.container`there? since i have made `canvas`and`.container`'s position to be `absolute`. i think the `<div>`should be overlapping it with `z-index:2`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you canvas element is going to fill the screen and all of your other content will appear below it. You should consider placing your canvas element at the end of your document and positioning it with CSS. See this article for more on positioning with CSS. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp